# Easy way to increment a demux without calling each pin every time?

Tags: c, avr, atmel, firmware

I need to increment through 2 demultiplexers. Right this moment I have it set up to where every time it just enables those specific pins as the output. I have been trying to wrap my head around an easy way to increment this in a function and or being able to call specific outputs? Or would the only way really would be to have a function called `void trigger(int output)` and have a switch statement within it for each of the 16 outputs and their associated pin triggers.

Increment the outputs through the various inputs. They are currently being used to drive a set of LEDs.

```c
        transformer(dv_out, 0); //recharge transformer
        module_0_SetHigh(); 
        module_1_SetHigh();
        if (!sec) {
            demux0_SetHigh();            
            demux0_SetLow();
        }
        if (sec) {
            demux1_SetHigh();            
            demux1_SetLow();
        }
        module_0_SetLow(); //disable pin select
        module_1_SetLow();
```

Comment: This question does not make much sense without context. Demuxes are not incremented. Demuxes are routing a single input into one of many outputs.

Comment: Increment the outputs through the various inputs. They are currently being used to drive a set of LEDs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", then come back and [edit] your question. Please post new information right into your question, not as comment. this is not a forum. Please provide some more context like a simplified schematic and a [example], what you like to do, and what you tried without success, and so on. Oh, and some decent indentation style would be nice to understand your source.